# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. Using MbnApi.dll

Tags: c#, access-violation

I had created a program about test file MbnApi.dll and this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MbnApi;

namespace TestMbnApi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            IMbnInterfaceManager infMgr = mbnInfMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;
            IMbnConnectionManager conManager = (IMbnConnectionManager)new MbnConnectionManager();
            // Connection
            IMbnConnection[] connections = conManager.GetConnections();
            IMbnConnection con = connections.First();
            // Get interfaceID
            String interfaceID = con.InterfaceID;
            Console.WriteLine("InterfaceID : {0}", interfaceID);
            // Get interface
            IMbnInterface interfa = infMgr.GetInterface(interfaceID) as IMbnInterface;
            // GetInterfaceCapability
            MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps =  interfa.GetInterfaceCapability();
            Console.WriteLine("Caps :{0}", caps);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When i build to file .exe and run on laptop windows 10 & have sim 3G. Then i received error :

```
Unhandled exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.StubHelpers.ValueClassMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr dst, IntPtr src, IntPtr pMT)
   at MbnApi.IMbnInterface.GetInterfaceCapability()
   at TestMbnApi.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I had using Frameword .Net 4.6.1 and Visual Studio 2015 Community version. I don't understand why this program error? Have anyone can support me about this.
Thanks all!

Comment: Where does the error occur? Have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: I have the same problem if I want to access the properties of `IMbnInterface`, such as `GetHomeProvider`. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I am glad that you found a solution for it but please research about the question before you post it. One more thing, `MbiApi` is not available with everyone, hence this code will not compile. Going forward if you use a special API, provide a link for others to download. Also, what has 3G sim to do with the code. Good information would have been OS + 64 or 32 bit. Example Win-x86 or Win-x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just resolved about this problem.
To fix this problem, please use MbnApi.dll corresponding to the operating system you are using. I'm using window 10 and i had built MbnApi.dll for this operating.
To build MbnApi.dll, i had got Window SDK version 10 following link below :
 [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk][1]

After downloaded Window SDK, please access to folder : 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64
Then copy file mbnapi.tlb to folder which contains file TlbImp.exe.
And access to the that folder and run command:
TlbImp.exe mbnapi.tlb /out:MbnApi.dll
So you build MbnApi.dll successfully.

Please try it and feedback to me if you have problem or success.

Thanks & Best Regard,